# Flutter Opening/Closing settings causes main() to be run again

Tags: android, flutter

I have an app that needs location to be turned on, so I've got something to open the location settings for them (testing on Android), so they can enable it, this works fine.

However, every time the settings are viewed and then closed (either via my app, or via just navigating to settings), I note in the app, main() seems to be called again (and hence all the various initStates and class variables etc are reset). So all the previous state is lost including whether I've displayed a location dialog already, as I don't want to repeat opening the settings dialog if they've discarded it.

Is this normal Android behaviour, to reset an app when a settings dialog is displayed ? If so, is there anything simple that can be used that persists data across this ?

Comment: That sounds like something strange going on - unless the phone is seriously low on memory the activity should persist long enough for the settings to be opened. It   might help if you listed which phone you're using. Also, check in your developer settings that you don't have the "Don't keep activities" flag set as that could explain why the activity is discarded.

Comment: Hah thanks, wasn't aware of 'don't keep activities'. That was ticked. If you want to set that as an answer, I'll accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android Developer settings have a toggle for `Don't Keep Activities` that can be set to simulate activities being closed early. If it is set, your activity will be closed as soon as you close your app.